# SQLite union columns

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, union

## My problem

I am actually developing an SQLite database for an android application. I come from MySQL, where the query I'll expose works nicely.

This is my database structure:

table1: `mid int(1) primary key autoincrement, name varchar(256)`

table2: `aid int(1) primary key autoincrement, name varchar(256)`

With data inserted:

table1, row1: `1, "abc"`

table2, row1: `1, "def"`

### What I want to do

I want to do a union so that the resulting data is:

```
| mid | aid | name |
--------------------
|  1  |  0  |"abc" |
|  0  |  1  |"def" |
```

So, I came up with this simple query:

`select mid, name, 0 as aid from table1 union select aid, name, 0 as mid from table2;`

However, I'm getting this back:

```
| mid | name | aid |
--------------------
|  1  |"abc" |  0  |
|  1  |"def" |  0  |
```

(I don't mind the column order)

This is of course not what I am looking for, and I can't see what I am doing wrong.

Any help will be appreciatted.

Thank you.

Comment: Edit: aid is actually 0 on the second "picture" for all rows, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's the column order that's tripping it up?

How about

```
select mid, 0 as aid, name from table1 union select 0 as mid, aid, name from table2;
```

works for me, at least on SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/157f09/1

Comment: Yes that was it, I just saw it now! Thank you! (stupid me...)